# Second moment of $S(T)$ for Dirichlet L-functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $S(T)$ denote the argument of the Riemann zeta function. Selberg established that $$\int_0^T |S(t)|^2 \text{d}t\sim\frac{T}{2\pi^2}\log \log T.$$ Let now $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $q$, and $S_\chi(T)$ the argument of the associated Dirichlet $L$-function. Is the main term of $$\int_0^T |S_\chi(t)|^2 \text{d}t $$ also known?